# The Office.context.officeTheme property is undefined

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

The property Office.context.officeTheme is undefined when used in the Outlook application: [Official documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.officetheme). In Word, Excel and PowerPoint, the property is defined and I can access its children properties (bodyBackgroundColor, controlForegroundColor, etc...). I tried with both latest (1.1.0.13) and previous (1.1.0.12) versions of Office.JS but it doesn't work. My outlook version is: 1711 (Build 8730.2127) and I also tried in the latest insiders build. Sample code:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // The "Office" object and its "context" property are valid but the "officeTheme" property is undefined.
            // This works in Word, Excel and PowerPoint but not in Outlook.
            if (!Office.context.officeTheme) {
                console.log("Office theme not loaded");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some example code?

Comment: I edited my initial post with the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Per information received from the product team, Outlook does not currently support the `office.context.officeTheme` property. Thanks for pointing out this problem with the docs (and for logging the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1262) as well). We'll update the docs to reflect that Outlook does not currently support this property.